# Javascript Regexp - not accepting space but it should

Tags: javascript, regex, input

I just want my input to accept only letters and spaces because my input serves for name and this doesn't work I already tried to put some space in the regex.
**My regex is working but spaces isn't.**

```
// without space
$('#name').on('input', function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z.,ñÑ ]/g, '');
});

// with space but it didnt work
$('#name').on('input', function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z .,ñÑ]/g, '');
});

// with space again but it fails work also
$('#name').on('input', function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z. ,ñÑ]/g, '');
});
```

Comment: space is a non-word character, so use \W for example

Comment: give us string example that you want to match with your regex, as you can see, there are several correct answers that from unknown reason don't work for you

Comment: Thats the thing, theres a lot of correct answers and i dont know what is the problem anymore why it didnt work for me thats why i came here. I just only need my input to accept letters and spaces including ñÑ.

Comment: this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z.\s,ñÑ]/g, '');

Comment: I just place my validation 2 times in different js the old one and other the reason why it didnt work correctly. I appreciate, thanks sir.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `\s` for single whitespace. Additionally `\s+` for matching multiple whitespaces

Comment: Space is not a special character in regex, hence it does not need to be escaped.

Comment: I just place my validation 2 times in different js the old one and other the reason why it didnt work correctly. I appreciate, thanks sir.

Comment: `\s` does not mean "single space"; it means "single whitespace". That means newlines, tabs, and vertical tabs would also match.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$('#name').keyup(function() {
  var new_value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z.\s,ñÑ]/g, '');
  this.value = new_value;
  
  $('#output').html(new_value);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='name'>

<div id='output'></div>
```

If you need to skip single whitespace character use `\s`,so use `/[^a-zA-Z.\s,ñÑ]/g` instead of `/[^a-zA-Z. ,ñÑ]/g`.

Comment: I just place my validation 2 times in different js the old one and other the reason why it didnt work correctly. I appreciate, thanks sir.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
this.value = this.value.replace(/[^a-zA-Z.,ñÑ\su00A0\u2008\u2009\u200A\u200B\u202F\uFEFF]/g, '');
```

This will identify many Unicode spaces, including the non-breaking space (U+00A0) that can crop up in HTML pages.  The others will match formatting spaces.  There are more unicode spaces, so if this doesn't work, we can add more codes.

Answer (score 0):

Use keydown event and cancel when `e.which || e.keyCode` not in allowed range.
Example:

```
$('#name').on('keydown', function(e){
   var key = e.which || e.keyCode;
   if(allowedKeysArray.indexOf(key) ==-1)
      return false;
});
```

`keydown` event in cancelable. `keyup`, `keypressed` and `input` are not. You can exclude numbers and most non-letter characters for sure. Minus - you cannot see characters, codes only.